# Is there an alternative to `groupBy` for this case?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have a map of `items`, the keys are item identifiers and the values are `Item` objects.

Each Item object have properties such that `id` (a string identifier) and `container` (the container to which it belongs). A `Container` is also an object it  has many properties but here only the `id` is needed.

I want to get the list of all containers identifiers (without repetition)

```kotlin
val containersIds : Set<String> = items.values.groupBy { item -> items.getValue(item.id).container.id }.keys
```

It does the job but maybe there is something else than using `groupBy` and `keys`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You just want the ID of each item's container, with no duplicates?

```
items.values().map { it.container.id }.distinct()
```

Or since you want a `Set` anyway, you get the uniqueness for free!

```
items.values().map { it.container.id }.toSet()
```

Or skip the `values` list and just work on the entries

```
items.map { (_, item) -> item.container.id }.toSet()
```